# Selenium "no such session" error on TestNG testing.xml

Tags: selenium, testng

I am trying to run a simple test with crossbrowsers using testing.xml of TestNG. Script runs fine on the first run which is Chrome. But gives "no such session" error on the firefox test beginning.

I simplified the codes to make it easy to read. I hope it helps.

Here's my TestNG testing.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="DefaultSuite" thread-count="1" parallel="tests">
    <test name="ChromeTest">
        <parameter name="browser" value="Chrome" />
        <classes>
            <class name="loginTest">
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="FirefoxTest">
        <parameter name="browser" value="Firefox" />
        <classes>
            <class name="loginTest">
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

And here's my code

```java
public class loginTest {
    private static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    @Parameters("browser")
    public void testSetup(String browser) throws Exception {
        //Check if parameter passed from TestNG is 'firefox'
        if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")){
            driver = webBrowsers.browserAl("Firefox");
        }
        //Check if parameter passed as 'chrome'
        else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")){
            driver = webBrowsers.browserAl("Chrome");
        }
        else{
            //If no browser passed throw exception
            throw new Exception("Browser is not correct");
        }
    }

    @Test(priority=0)
    public void LoginTest(){
        driver.get("http://www.hurriyet.com.tr/");
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void kapat() {
        webBrowsers.closeDriver();
    }
}
```

and finally my webBrowsers.class

```java
public class webBrowsers {
    private static WebDriver driver = null;
    private static String browserName;

    public static WebDriver browserAl(String browserName) {

        if (browserName.equals("Firefox")) {
            if (driver == null) {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","./drivers/geckodriver.exe");
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            }
        } else if (browserName.equals("Edge")) {
            if (driver == null) {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "./drivers/MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");
                driver = new EdgeDriver();
            }
        } else if (browserName.equals("Chrome")) {
            if (driver == null) {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","./drivers/chromedriver.exe");
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
            }
        }
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return driver;
    }

    public static void closeDriver() {
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your class `webBrowsers`. You are working with a static webdriver instance. So for the first `<test>` execution the `driver` instance will not be null and it would get instantiated properly. But when you execute the second `<test>` tag, the condition `driver == null` would be false, and you end up getting reference to the webdriver object that was created for the previous `<test>` tag. To make matters worse, you have a `@AfterTest` method which cleans up the driver instance as well. So you are now essentially working with a valid `webdriver` instance but for which the opened session has already been cleaned up.

End result : Your error.

Here's a cleaned up version of your code that should get past this problem.

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class WebBrowsers {
    public static WebDriver browserAl(String browserName) {
        WebDriver driver = null;

        if (browserName.equals("Firefox")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "./drivers/geckodriver.exe");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        } else if (browserName.equals("Edge")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "./drivers/MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");
            driver = new EdgeDriver();
        } else if (browserName.equals("Chrome")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./drivers/chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return driver;
    }

    public static void closeDriver(WebDriver driver) {
        if (driver != null) {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's how your test class would look like

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class LoginTest {
    private WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    @Parameters("browser")
    public void testSetup(String browser) throws Exception {
        //Check if parameter passed from TestNG is 'firefox'
        if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
            driver = WebBrowsers.browserAl("Firefox");
        }
        //Check if parameter passed as 'chrome'
        else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
            driver = WebBrowsers.browserAl("Chrome");
        } else {
            //If no browser passed throw exception
            throw new Exception("Browser is not correct");
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void loginTest() {
        driver.get("http://www.hurriyet.com.tr/");
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void kapat() {
        WebBrowsers.closeDriver(driver);
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not change anything.org.openqa.selenium.New error message is "NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?"

Comment: I guessed the reason of the error as you explained but could not find a solution. driver object is declared in the beginning of the class and becomes "null" at the end of the first loop. I don't have any idea how to recreate it.

Comment: @CeyhunGanioğlu - What loop are you talking about ? As long as you have only one `<class>` entry per `<test>` your code should be fine. But if you have more than one `<class>` in your `<test>` then you are definitely going to see problems.

Comment: Krishnan I am talking about the browser loop coming from TestNG.xml. No matter what I write quit() or close() to the "@AfterTest" section, my kapat() function seems to be removing the session or driver. It simply does not work. Does it work on your computer?

Comment: @ceyhun the code I shared in my answer is a working code. Do you see errors when you run that ?

Comment: at the first browser it executes fine. But in the beginning of the second browser (after the quit() or close() command executed) I get error message. 

1- quit() : org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?

2- close() : org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: no such session

So basicly it runs perfect at the first execution coming from the TestNG.xml but not on the second.

Comment: Can you please copy paste and run my code ? You are obviously missing some minute details